# Update EndPeriodTime with next records StartPeriodTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, versioning

I have a table with a StartPeriodTime and an EndPeriodTtime to help separate versions of the same account. When a new record is added for that particular account the previous record EndPeriodTime should be the StartPeriodTime of the new record.

Currently it is not updating and I need to apply an update that will allow me to take care of this. The only EndPeriodTime that should be left as default should be the newest record. I have came up with code that works, but it is only working sometimes.

If I was to load the table all at once with all my files it works great. If I was to load my table one file at a time it is failing because it is getting nulls. I need help writing this to where it doesn't pick up nulls. I am even open to writing it another way if someone can provide me with a workable solution. My code is below:

```
UPDATE ods.CustomerPayment
    SET EndPeriodTime = (
        SELECT MIN(t2.EndPeriodTime)
        FROM ods.CustomerPayment t2
        WHERE t2.CustomerNumber = t1.CustomerNumber
        AND t2.StartPeriodTime > t1.StartPeriodTime
    )
FROM ods.CustomerPayment t1
WHERE t1.EndPeriodTime != '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `lag()` and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cp.*,
            lead(startperiodtime) over (partition by CustomerNumber) as next_startperiodtime
      from ods.CustomerPayment cp
     )
    set endperiodtime = next_startperiodtime
    where (endperiodtime <> next_startperiodtime or endperiodtime is null) and
          endperiodtime <> '1999-01-01';
```

You don't explain the significance of `'1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'`, so I have not included that logic.

Comment: the newest record has a default date of '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'. However all the records need to be updated before the newest version and those currently have the same value. So anything below the max version needs to be updated

Comment: @an1234 . . . That is a really silly value for the end date of the *newest* version.  First, it is in the past.  Why not just use `NULL`?  Or at least some arbitrary future date, such as 2199-12-31?

Comment: Someone had initially developed the table an I am trying to maintain it. Can you provide me with logic to update those except the newest record. My current query worked but was returning nulls if I loaded once at a time

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
update ods.CustomerPayment 
set EndPeriodTime = t1.EndPeriodTime2
from 
    (select t.EndPeriodTime as EndPeriodTime2, t.CustomerNumber as CustomerNumber2 from 
        (select row_number() over (order by EndPeriodTime desc) rn
            , EndPeriodTime
            , CustomerNumber
            from ods.CustomerPayment) t
        where t.rn = 2) t1
where  EndPeriodTime != '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    and CustomerNumber = t1.CustomerNumber2
```

Comment: @metal it doesn't like the last and statement in the final line of code. throws an error for ambiguous column because the CustomerNumber does not specify what table it is coming from

Comment: @an1234,try now

Comment: @metal still doesn't work I think it is because of the subquery for some reason it doesn't understand not really sure why

Comment: @metal Shouldn't we be setting it equal to StartPeriodTime? Since I am wanting to set EndPeriodTime equal to next records startPeriodTime?